# How to make git push run faster

Tags: git, github, git-push

Is there a way to tell git to push the changes to the github remote server a little faster. It takes a longer time (~8-10 secs) even for minor changes on few files in a bare minimal rails application.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try creating a directory `~/.ssh/control` and then adding this to your `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host github.com
  ControlMaster auto
  ControlPath ~/.ssh/control/%r@%h:%p
  ControlPersist 3600
```

This will cause ssh to reuse existing connections to github for one hour, which will eliminate the time taken to reauthenticate during that time.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using http/https protocol, you should try ssh protocol.